# Understanding slicing behavior in custom PyTorch Dataset class with tuple return type in __getitem__ method

Tags: python, pytorch

I wrote the following dataset class:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import json

def read_dataset(path: str) -> tuple[list[list[str]], list[list[str]]]:
    tokens_s, labels_s = [], []

    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            data = json.loads(line)
            assert len(data["tokens"]) == len(data["labels"])
            tokens_s.append(data["tokens"])
            labels_s.append(data["labels"])

    assert len(tokens_s) == len(labels_s)

    return tokens_s, labels_s


class EventDetectionDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path: str) -> None:
        self.tokens, self.labels = read_dataset(path)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.tokens)

    def __getitem__(self, index) -> tuple[list[str], list[str]]:
        return self.tokens[index], self.labels[index]
```

As you can see, we have that `EventDetectionDataset.__getitem__(idx) -> tuple[list[str], list[str]]`

Why when I print the first two items of the dataset, do I get a tuple of lists of lists of strings and not a list of tuples of lists of strings?

```
train = EventDetectionDataset("path/to/data/train.jsonl")
train = train[:2]
```

Returns:

```
(
    [
        ['Hard', 'Rock', 'Hell', 'III', ':', 'The', 'Vikings', 'Ball', '.'],
        ['Casualties', 'and', 'damage', 'were', 'severe', 'on', 'both', 'sides', ',', 'and', 'the', 'defiance', 'of', 'the', 'French', 'ship', 'was', 'celebrated', 'in', 'both', 'countries', 'as', 'a', 'brave', 'defence', 'against', 'overwhelming', 'odds', '.']
    ],

     [
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['B-SCENARIO', 'O', 'B-CHANGE', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ACTION', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
    ]
)
```

In other words, why do I get an object of type `tuple[list[list[str]], list[list[str]]]` and not an object of type `list[tuple[list[str], list[str]]]`?

It seems that slicing a dataset that returns a tuple from its `__getitem__` method causes the individual elements in the returned tuple to be concatenated into a list. Is this right? Why is this behaviour modeled?

Comment: How was `train` first initialized?

Comment: Have you used any type checker to confirm that your code is correctly typed? Type hints don't affect runtime behavior, but they *can* confirm that the code you wrote is not consistent with the types you are assuming.

Comment: @chepner I have already _manually_ checked that the type annotations are correct and correspond to the objects I see at runtime. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan I've edited the question to add the line that creates the Dataset instance `train`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**The key issue here is the difference between slicing and indexing.**

When Dataset classes are sliced PyTorch does not use the `__getitem__` method to return a sequence of items where each item is returned by a single call to `__getitem__`. Instead it references the underlying data objects in the Dataset class and returns sequences of those objects respectively.

In order to handle slicing, one can explicitly define behaviour to handle slicing, as follows:

```
class EventDetectionDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path: str) -> None:
        self.tokens, self.labels = read_dataset(path)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.tokens)

    def __getitem__(self, index) -> TokenLabelPair | list[TokenLabelPair]:
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return [self.__getitem__(i) for i in range(*index.indices(len(self)))]  # type: ignore
        else:
            return self.tokens[index], self.labels[index]
```

This returns the desired objects, such that if we define the type alias:

```
TokenLabelPair = tuple[list[str], list[str]]
```

for the type of an object returned indexing into the Dataset with an integer index, a slice into the dataset results in the desired object type, which is a list of token-label pairs: `list[TokenLabelPair]`.